# Can Notepad++ run a Ruby (or other) script directly on text in active tab?

Tags: notepad++

I know that I can run a Ruby script in my active tab with the command

```
cmd /K ruby “$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)”
```

However, I'd like to do with Notepad++ on my Windows system what I do regularly in BBEdit on my Mac: Have a text file open and then call a Ruby script from a menu, and have that script act on text in my active window *without having to actually input the name of the file*. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

To run a Ruby script in Notepad++, first install the [NppExec plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) if it’s not already installed.
Then in Notepad++ either hit F6 or go to Plugins > NppExec > Execute.
In the Execute Command dialog type in the  following:

```
ruby "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

[See this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_command_line_options.htm) for additional commandline options

Comment: Right, thanks, but can I get that Ruby script to run on text in an open active tab without having to enter the filename of that text file in the Ruby script?

Comment: Appreciate the Google search on my behalf, but I also did several those before posting here. I do already have the NppExec plugin to Run Ruby scripts. The only difference between that and the code I wrote above is that it runs in a console within Notepad++ , but that still makes me manually enter the filename each time I want to run a Ruby script on a text file. I was hoping to find something easier and more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` is the full path of the file in the currently active tab, which would contain the text of the current tab.

So you could save the current file and then execute

```
ruby /path/to/your/script.rb "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

I don't know why you have to keep typing in the name of the file, but you can press `Ctrl+F6` after the first run to re-run the previous command directly.